# Get data from json with javascript more than one data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I have a question about getting data from json with javascript. I have a form. I want to fill this form with data from json. Now I can do this with this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input id="name_1" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" />
        <input id="surname_1" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" type="text" value="" />
        <select id="gender_1" name="gender">
          <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Gender</option>
          <option value="F">Female</option>
          <option value="M">Male</option>
          <option value="N">None.</option>
        </select>
        <input id="day_1" maxlength="2" name="day" placeholder="GG" type="text" value="" />
        <select id="month_1" name="month">
          <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Month</option>
          <option value="1">Jan</option
          ><option value="2">Feb</option>
          <option value="3">Mar</option>
          <option value="4">Apr</option>
          <option value="5">May</option>
          <option value="6">Jun</option>
          <option value="7">Jul</option>
          <option value="8">Aug</option>
          <option value="9">Sep</option>
          <option value="10">Oct</option>
          <option value="11">Nov</option
          ><option value="12">Dec</option>
         </select>
        <input id="year_1" maxlength="4" name="year" placeholder="YYYY" type="text" value="" />
    </form>

    <script>
        var data = {
            "name": "Jack",
            "surname": "Rynold",
            "gender": "M",
            "day": 12,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 1995,
        };

        for (key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key))
                $('input[name=' + key + ']').val(data[key]);
            $('select[name=' + key + ']').val(data[key]);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now output is like that
[image: output1]

But if the data is more than one, I also want to open a new form like this.

Data:

```
var data = [{
            "name": "Jack",
            "surname": "Rynold",
            "gender": "M",
            "day": 12,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 1995,
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Rynold",
            "gender": "M",
            "day": 30,
            "month": 4,
            "year": 1996,
        }
        ];
```

Expected Output:
[image: expected output]

How can I do that?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this with jQuery. Add a class to your `<form class="client form">` Iterate over your array, and at each iteration clone the initial form and append the cloned instance to the DOM mapping in your client object attrs to the correct fields like you're already doing.

https://api.jquery.com/clone/